# Python - Determine Matrix cells are a group

Tags: python

Given a set of tuples which represent the position in the matrix.

```
for example {(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)}
```

where a tuple (r,k) represents the row r and the column k.
How can I determine if they hang together?

```
examples 
{(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)} => hangs together
{(1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)} => doesnt hang together
```

Comment: What do you mean by "hang together"?

Answer (score 1):

I'd just do simple BFS or DFS, for example:

```
def connected(cells):
    if cells:
        cells = cells.copy()
        stack = [cells.pop()]
        while stack:
            i, j = stack.pop()
            neighbors = {(i-1, j), (i+1, j), (i, j-1), (i, j+1)} & cells
            stack.extend(neighbors)
            cells -= neighbors
    return not cells
```

Usage/demo:

```
for cells in ({(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)},
              {(1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)}):
    print(connected(cells))
```

Prints:

```
True
False
```